# How to use @MockBean and MockMvc to append some data with HTTP POST to a mocked repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test

I have a controller with a POST action, that creates a new `BLOGPOST` and return all the `BLOGPOSTS` including the newly created one:

```
@Autowired
private BlogPostInMemRepository bpr;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path="/post",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<BlogPost> addPost(BlogPost post) {
    bpr.addPost(post);
    return bpr.getAllPosts();
}
```

The BlogPostInMemRepository code looks like this:

```
@Repository
public class BlogPostInMemRepository {

    private List<BlogPost> posts = new ArrayList<BlogPost>(){{
        add(new BlogPost(1, "Author1", "Post 1"));
        add(new BlogPost(2, "Author2", "Post 2"));
    }};

    public List<BlogPost> getAllPosts(){
        return posts;
    }

    public void addPost(BlogPost post){
        posts.add(post);
    }
}
```

My goal is to unit test the controller using @MockBean and MockMvc. The steps would be:

- Mock the BlogPostInMemRepository injecting some initial data into it
- Issue a post request with `mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/post")`
- Get back the initial post with the new post successfully added.

My current tests:

```
@Test
public void post_whenValidParametersPassed_addsAndReturnsAllBlogPostsSuccessfully() throws Exception {
    // given
    BlogPost bp1 = new BlogPost(1, "John", "Post 1");
    BlogPost bp2 = new BlogPost(2, "Jack", "Post 2");
    List<BlogPost> posts = new ArrayList<BlogPost>(){{ add(bp1); add(bp2); }};
    given(repo.getAllPosts()).willReturn(posts);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/post")
        .contentType(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
        .param("id", "33")
        .param("author", "Gibraltar")
        .param("post", "There is now way!"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string("{... the whole string ...}"))
        .andDo(print());
}
```

What I get is just the posts passed in: `given(repo.getAllPosts()).willReturn(posts);` - which is expected, of course.

**QUESTION**: how to actually inject the initial set of `BLOGPOSTS`, add one more with `POST` and get all of them back from a mocked repository?

Comment: If it is an in-memory repo then why would actually need to mock it? The impl seems simple enough

Comment: Thanks for the question. It will be replaced by a SQL backed repo at a latter stage. At that point I will want to just reuse the same tests - therefore I wanted to do this with mocking from the begging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using `doCallRealMethod()` and `when().thenCallRealMethod()` - this seems to be the only way to inject controller data from "down-below (bottom-up)" using Mockito, as direct setters do not work on `@MockBean`'s.

Code:

```
@Test
public void post_whenValidParametersPassedAndPreExistingBlogsPresent_addsAndReturnsAllBlogPostSuccessfully() throws Exception {
    // given : initialize mock data
    BlogPost bp1 = new BlogPost(1, "John", "Post 1");
    BlogPost bp2 = new BlogPost(2, "Jack", "Post 2");
    List<BlogPost> posts = new ArrayList<BlogPost>(){{ add(bp1); add(bp2); }};

    // given : prep the mocked object
    doCallRealMethod().when(repo).setPosts(posts);
    doCallRealMethod().when(repo).addPost(any(BlogPost.class));
    repo.setPosts(posts);
    when(repo.getAllPosts()).thenCallRealMethod();

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/post")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) //from MediaType
            .param("id", "33")
            .param("author", "Gibraltar")
            .param("post", "There is now way!"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("[" +
                    "{\"id\":1,\"author\":\"John\",\"post\":\"Post 1\"}," +
                    "{\"id\":2,\"author\":\"Jack\",\"post\":\"Post 2\"}," +
                    "{\"id\":33,\"author\":\"Gibraltar\",\"post\":\"There is now way!\"}" +
                "]"))
            .andDo(print());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to mock the repository it does not really make much sense to follow your approach as the `addPost` will have no effect and `getAllPosts` would just assume it has been added. It seems a bit artificial and not bring any real value testing-wise.

What I would do here is to use a simple in-order verification:

```
InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(brp);
inOrder.verify(brp).addPost(any(Post.class));
inOrder.verify(brp).getAllPosts();
```

So to make sure the post is added before all of them are fetched from the repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like an explanation as to why `not bring any real value testing-wise` ? There is indeed little value since the controllers are simple and don't have any intelligence (like returning different status codes depending on some conditions). But I plan to add more logic into them and it would be beneficial for me to have control over the data layer from the test itself.

Comment: IF you want to mock your repo it means you do not care what happens inside it. And you want to theoretically assume that a post is persisted. You can just create a list to return with that additonal post from the start as there is nothing that will add it explicitly while running the test.